# What is the quickest way to get exp on a factions server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've got a faction in Minecraft and I really want to enchant my bow, however it is taking a long time to get exp from blaze spawners, zombie pigmen spawners, and creeper spawners.

Is there a way to quickly get EXP without using spawners, PVP or using any weapons? Ideally it should also be cheap to do. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a way that everyone could use? Like, anyone on a server could enchant basically for free? Or would you prefer a secret method only you will use?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the nether, mining nether quartz is a very efficient way to gather exp. The abundance of nether quartz and amount of exp it gives you allows for quite a quick grind to level 30 when compared to other methods. It may be considered unorthodox though

Comment: Being that this is a public server, the chances of finding large and plentiful sources of Quartz is limited due to the number of players who have already likely scoured the entire nether for all its quartz.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest way to make exp is enderfarms, but its requires alot of work.